# How can I Publish my WCF Service?

Tags: wcf, localhost, nat

I want to use my webservice on internet. I opened my port which is 4501 an I disabled firewall on modem and on windows. I can write my global ip and I can open modem control inteface. But I want to connect to iis which address is xx.xx.xx.xx:4501/Products.svc

It works on localhost (http://localhost:4501/Product.svc) But I cant connect to svc on internet ..

I dont know where is problem.

When I add my svc link addres as adding reference service I got this error

```
  There was an error downloading 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4501/Products.svc'.
  Unable to connect to the remote server
  Hedef makine etkin olarak reddettiğinden bağlantı kurulamadı xx.xx.xx.xx:4501
  Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:                         'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4501/Products.svc'.
  There was no endpoint listening at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4501/Products.svc that could           accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See    InnerException, if present, for more details.
  Unable to connect to the remote server
  Hedef makine etkin olarak reddettiğinden bağlantı kurulamadı xx.xx.xx.xx:4501
  If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and      adding the service reference again.
```

And One point more,

If I start to IIS, wcf service doesnt work even in localhost. If I start it in Visual Studio (I mean asp.net development service works) it works..

IIS version is 7.5.7600 and I added application pool as Asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you use port 4501 for HTTP in IIS?

Visual Studio 2010 WebDev WebServer (Cassini) uses random port number (4501 in your case) to simplify configuration. It assumes that port 80 can be occupied by its big brother IIS or any other software.

That is fine for development in local machine but there is no need to use the same port in production.

Default HTTP port is 80 and it is usually the most open open port in networks.

Use port 80 for HTTP traffic in IIS and your life will be much easier.

P.S. Did you try http://xx.xx.xx.xx/Products.svc?  Port number is part of web service configuration and it is not copied when you move app to IIS. It is possible that IIS already uses default HTTP port.

Comment: thank you for answer. I changed port as 80 and when i wrote my ip lie http://xx.xx.xx.xx, modem interface is opened  still.. and when I try http://xx.xx.xx.xx/Products.svc I get this error Object Not Found

The requested URL '/Products.svc' was not found on the RomPager Advanced server.  And It works http://localhost/Products.svc

Comment: @HarunAbi IIS now works fine. You need to resolve a network configuration issue. I am not an expert in that. Sorry. I would suggest to add more network details and tags to your question.